# Make image wider than parent <div> while preserving vertical space?

Tags: html, css

If you have a parent `div` of fixed width, is it possible to make a child `<img>` wider than the parent, while constraining proportions, while also preserving vertical space?

While `position:absolute;` can break the image out of the normal document flow, I don't want to remove the vertical space the image retains. If I did, any content that appears after the image would be pushed upwards, and as a result, it would appear behind the image.

[Here's an example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s5hf3aqc/2/)

Image one represents the vertical behavior I want. Obviously, if the image were horizontally larger, the height should increase proportionally. Image two represents the horizontal behavior I would want. However, this does not preserve vertical space. I experimented with negative margins, but couldn't get anything viable working.

Assuming unknown image dimensions, is the desired effect possible without JavaScript?

Comment: Would it be ok to use some evtra markup like a div around the image?

Comment: Ideally, no. However, if it cannot be done any other way, then any solution is better than no solution!

Comment: Sorry, my train of thought went to the wrong direction. I'm pretty sure the answer is no, even with extra markup.

Comment: do you need the image to keep it's natural size or should it have a percentage width?

Comment: I think a percentage width would be fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w5o8Lytz/1/ jquey based soln checkitout

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify this: does the image height have to be limited somehow? `I think a percentage width would be fine` -- a percentage width of what exactly? The viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once browser support catches up, you could consider using `calc` to apply a negative margin.

**[DEMO using `calc()`](http://jsbin.com/rozafa/1/edit)**

```
html {
  font-size: 10px; /* Set a base value for easy math, or for sane defaults */
}

body {
  background-color: #FC9;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  font-size: 1.9rem; /* Or whatever */
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3rem;
  width: 400px;
}

#wrapper img.one {
  display: block;
  margin: 3rem 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper img.two {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  /* 
   * Math break: 
   *   viewport width: 100vw
   *   #wrapper width: 400px
   *   remainder: (100vw - 400px)
   *   want to shift the image by half of the remainder, so: (100vw - 400px) / 2
   *   and apply it as a negative margin: -1 * (100vw - 400px) / 2)
   */
  margin: 3rem 0;
  margin-left: -webkit-calc(-1 * (100vw - 400px) / 2);
  margin-left: calc(-1 * (100vw - 400px) / 2);
}
```

If your requirements for a fixed-width `#wrapper` element aren't firm, you could actually use `vw` for the whole thing, as in:

```
#wrapper {
  ...
  width: 40vw;
}
```

Which simplifies the `margin-left` declaration to use hardcoded `vw` units, which has better browser support:

```
#wrapper img.two {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  /* 
   * Math break: 
   *   viewport width: 100vw
   *   #wrapper width: 40vw
   *   remainder: 100vw - 40vw = 60vw
   *   want to shift the image by half of the remainder, so: 60vw / 2 = 30vw
   *   and apply it as a negative margin: -30vw
   */
  margin: 3rem 0 3rem -30vw;
}
```

**[DEMO of straight-up `vw`](http://jsbin.com/xodewo/1/edit)**

In that case, if this design needs to support screen widths below which the `40vw` of your content wrapper looks gross, you'll either need to use a media query to assign a higher % of the viewport width to `#wrapper`, or to degrade the design so that it uses different layout calculations and doesn't use the content-spanning image.

Comment: This is the best answer, in my opinion. Thanks Palpatim! However, Bodzio's solution with `translateX()` provides an alternative, interesting solution. Everyone give him upvotes too!

Answer (score 8):

Try with this:

```css
#wrapper img.two {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

`width: 100vw` will make image stretch to screen width, `margin-left: 50%` will center left border of image to the center of the wrapper, and then `transform: translateX(-50%)` will move image 50% of its width to the left.

You can set image width to whatever you want. It will stay centered and it will have margins at the top and bottom.

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7cjr6jff/

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. I like it! I chose the other answer because it was slightly more logical (in my mind) but this is a very neat solution. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I like this one better than my solution since it doesn't rely on hardcoded values and math to achieve the correct result.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I didn't investigate very closely initially, and didn't realize this one actually omits the need to know the parent's container. That's pretty neat!

Comment: Excellent solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
by this code you don't need to change margin from top or bottom

<style>
.wrapper
{
width: 400px;
margin:auto;
background:#e6e6e6;
}

.wrapper img
{
width:120%;
clear:left;
margin-left:-10%;
}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">

Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu
<img src="http://wallpoper.com/images/00/31/09/01/pokemon-pikachu_00310901.jpg" />
Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu Pikachu
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of the famous "padding-bottom" hack. since `padding-bottom` is always relative to its element's width, you can use the proportion of the image as its `padding-bottom` to keep the desired height while still being responsive.

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: ...px;
    height: 0; // very important!
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; // image ratio in % - 16:9 for example
    overflow: hidden;
}
div > img { 
     position: absolute;
     width: ...;
     height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This only works if you know the image dimensions, unfortunately.

Comment: mhhh - now i also saw your last sentence ;) you are of course right - that would require some JS to apply inline `padding-bottom` with the correct ratio - would that help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow for another `<div>` to wrap around each image, this can be done quite easily.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   text blah blah
   <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="pic.jpg"/>
   </div>
   more text blah blah
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 400px;
}

.image-wrapper {
    width: 200%;
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
}

.image-wrapper img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

Basically you're wrapping the image in a very wide `<div>` so you can center the image inside it.

Adjust the numbers as you need. The `max-width: 80%` is 80% of the 200%, so the image is actually 160% the width of your large `#wrapper`.

Here's a fiddle based on yours: http://jsfiddle.net/bdh0mrLs/

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#wrapper img.one {
display: block;
margin: 30px auto;
width: 130%;
margin-left:-15%;
}
```

Here's the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDsouza/pdefev14/)

Basically set the width to something higher that 100% and the "15%" margin came from

```
130/2 - 50
(width / 2) - 50
```

which should center it.

P.S : I came up with this based on your question. However your jsfiddle seems like you want the image to be 100% width of the body. Just needed clarification if that's what your expecting. Could try working around that instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try with overflow-y: hidden while keeping overflow-x: visible in the parent div.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question being asked as it only deals with overflow, not dimensions